# MSTest, how to block other classes from running while the single class is running

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest

Good day all,

I have set up 2 example.  One with my web browser closing and opening on each testmethod and another example with my browser close and opening at the start of the class.

However, when i run both classes at the same time, the test method execution is random.

I want them to perform all of one class at a time, instead of having the methods being chosen randomly.

For example:  I want my test cases to assume location on a website.

```
[Test Class]
public class Example1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Login() {}

    [TestMethod]
    public void Settings() {}

    [TestMethod]
    public void Admin() {}

    [TestMethod]
    public void Logout {}
}


[Test Class]
public class Example2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Register() {}

    [TestMethod]
    public void Help() {}

    [TestMethod]
    public void Post() {}
}
```

In the above example, we have 2 different class examples.

They both fall under the same DLL, so when i execute that DLL, mstest runs the methods at random, or at the very least alphabetical order.

Actual Execution Order:
Admin, Help, Login, Logout, Post, Register, Settings

Expected Execution Order:
Login, Settings, Admin, Help, Post, Logout, Register

I understand in MSTest V1 there is something called Ordered Tests, however; I am using MSTest V2 and VS Community.

I require a solution that allows me to order my tests.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your question.  We cannot help you if we cannot find the source of the problem.  I.e. post some code so we can help you find the problems.

Comment: Perhaps an [ordered test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms182630(v=vs.90)) ist the way to go?

Comment: I have updated my question,  Ordered Tests would work if they worked in MSTestV2.  Or in VS Community, but as far as i know they dont. :(